# Faster version of lme4 for logistic regression 3-level multilevel model in R with 2 million data points

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, glmm

I'm running a 3-level multilevel model in R with binary outcomes and survival analysis with over 2 million data points. The `lme4` package takes 12 hours to run one model or just crashes.

The simplest model is:

```
library(lme4)
library(lmerTest)
model0 <- glmer(death ~ 1 + (1|id_household), data=df, family="binomial)
```

I tried adding an optimizer:

```
model0 <- glmer(death ~ 1 + (1|id_household), data=df, family="binomial, control = glmerControl(optimiser = "bobyqa", optCtrl = list(maxfun=200000)
```

Which also works very slowly. Can anyone suggest an alternative package?

Comment: This *may* be closed as off-topic because it's focussed on programming ('alternative package'), but I think it ought to be suitable, at least after a bit of modification. Efficient/optimised fitting routines should fall within our remit.

Comment: Use basic principles of computing and statistics.  In particular, *benchmark* your program on smaller versions of the problem and create those smaller versions through *random sampling.*  I suspect you will discover that you get adequate results with relatively tiny samples that take little time to compute.

Comment: Really helpful - thank you very much - I'll try that. Does anyone know how to run a survival multilevel analysis for this multilevel model (number of days to death and death binary)?